# Marginal means confidence interval

Tags: matlab, mean, marginal-distribution, lsmeans

Let's say that I have 4 groups and I want to report whether there are significant differences between them in terms of a measured variable.

Each group has different numbers of male/female and different numbers of subjects with age<67/age>67

```
     G1                     ....           G4
Sex  Age  Variable measured          Sex  Age  Variable measured
 M   <67   2                          F   <67   2
 M   >67   3                          F   >67   1
     ...                                  ...
 F   >67   3                          M   <67   5
```

To compute the adjusted means I compute for each group the means of the subgroups

```
Male   >67 years 
Male   <67 years
Female >67 years
Female <67 years
```

and then I average these means. How do I compute the 95% confidence intervals? How do I see whether the means computed in such a way are significantly different?

I cannot use ANOVA because the data do not respect the assumptions.

Comment: I think a big question for you to consider is if it’s even the mean that you want to examine. Perhaps testing medians would be better for your data.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable being measured is continuous and your data does not follow a normal distribution, then calculate each group's median and interquartile range. Then use the Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test to test whether they have equal medians. Here's the MATLAB code: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ranksum.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s better to plot data before summarizing. For example, you can create box plots by each category that you specified. Then, you can summarize data by using summary statistics such as quintile range, and perform statistical test if you find some trends,